# Why is there a "SocketException: Connection reset" when not closing client's output stream?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, socketexception

In a simple Server Client communication I always get the "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" on the serverside, if the client does not close the outputstream of it's socket directly after sending out the data via BufferedWriter.
If I close the client's outputstream everything works fine.
But obviously the client wants eventually to send more than one String (then the server needs to handle the connection in a new Thread). But I don't even get that far, because ofe the problem above...

Thanks for helping!!

Here is some condensed code to show the problem.

This is the server class:

```
public class TestServerCharacterStream {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("### Started");
        TestServerCharacterStream testServerCharacterStream = new TestServerCharacterStream(9498);
        testServerCharacterStream.waitForData();
        System.out.println("### Terminated");
    }
    
    
    private int port;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public TestServerCharacterStream(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("[SERVER] :   Server started!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open new server socket!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void waitForData() {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("[SERVER] :   Wait for data on port " + port + " ...");
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String incoming = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("[SERVER] :   Incoming message: " + incoming);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error while accepting connection or reading input!");
            closeStreamAndSocket(clientSocket, in);
            closeServerSocket();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeStreamAndSocket(Socket socket, BufferedReader in) {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot close stream or socket.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void closeServerSocket() {
        try {
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot close serverSocket.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Client Class:
As mentioned, it works if closing the outputstream (see the comment). To use flush() or not does not make any difference. The only way to solve it is `out.close();`
But I want to use the BufferedWriter again, withot connect always again to the server.

```
public class TestClientCharacterStream {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("### Started");
        TestClientCharacterStream testClientCharacterStream = new TestClientCharacterStream("localhost", 9498);
        testClientCharacterStream.sendData("Hello!!!");
        System.out.println("### Terminated");
    }
    
    
    private InetSocketAddress adress;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedWriter out;
    
    public TestClientCharacterStream(String serverIp, int port) {
        this.adress = new InetSocketAddress(serverIp, port);
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket();
            clientSocket.connect(adress, 10000);
            this.out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Something went wrong on instantiating a new TestClientCharacterStream");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void sendData(String string) {
        try {   
            out.write(string);
            System.out.println("[CLIENT] :   Sent new message: " + string);
                        out.flush();
            out.close(); // If I don't close the stream, I'm going to get a "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" on the server          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            closeStreamAndSocket(clientSocket, out);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    
    private void closeStreamAndSocket(Socket socket, BufferedWriter out) {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot close stream or socket.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The servers Output:

```
### Started
[SERVER] :   Server started!
[SERVER] :   Wait for data on port 9498 ...
Error while accepting connection or reading input!
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:177)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:162)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at TestServerCharacterStream.waitForData(TestServerCharacterStream.java:40)
    at TestServerCharacterStream.main(TestServerCharacterStream.java:12)
### Terminated
```

Comment: You get this error if the client closes the socket without closing the stream.